# retrieve some data from the firebase database with some nodes being null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

```
cBankRef=myRef.child("user_id").child("ASSETS");


 cBankRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        String value = dataSnapshot.child("1").child("description").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: the value is"+value);


                        if(dataSnapshot.child("2").exists()) {
                            String valuess = dataSnapshot.child("3").child("description").getValue(String.class);
                            Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: the value is: " + valuess);

                        }
                        if (dataSnapshot.child("3").exists()) {
                            String values = dataSnapshot.child("1").child("description").getValue(String.class);
                            Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: the cash at bank is: "+values);
                        }

                        }



                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

first i accessed the user_id child and the ASSETS then through the nodes ("1"),("2")  i had to add other nodes in order to get the value, the("1") and ("2") were ("Cash at Bank") ("stock") in the beginning but i decided to change them to numbers but it's giving null @makrand pawar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues in your example:

- Your `cBankRef` is pointing to `\user_id\ASSETS\Cash at bank\stock\Cash in Hand`, which does not exist (`Cash at bank` node does not exist under `ASSETS`).
- You are then attaching a `ChildEventListener` to this reference, which won't return any values, because there aren't any children under it (as it doesn't exist).
- Inside `onChildAdded()`, you are trying to access the `houses` node which also doesn't exist in your example (`house` does though).

To access the children under the `Stock` node, you'll need something like:

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user_id").child("ASSETS").child("Stock");

ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String value = dataSnapshot.child("house").child("values").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: the value is: "+value);
    }
    // ...
});
```

The [`DatabaseReference#child()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#child(java.lang.String)) method is **not** a `SELECT` statement. To access everything underneath a node, you only need to create a reference to the highest node required, then attach a listener to that.

For example, if you need access to everything underneath the `ASSETS` node, you could attach a listener there instead:

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user_id").child("ASSETS");

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String value = dataSnapshot.child("Stock").child("house").child("values").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: the value is: "+value);

        if (dataSnapshot.child("Cash at bank").exists()) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.child("Cash at bank").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: the cash at bank is: "+value);
        }
    }
    // ...
});
```

Then when the listener returns you can use [`DataSnapshot#child()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#child(java.lang.String)) instead to access the individual values retrieved from that location. Also, using [`DataSnapshot#exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#exists(java.lang.String)) is a simple way to check that a node exists before using it.

If you plan to have additional values or nodes under `ASSETS` that don't currently exist, they will be returned by the above listener as soon as they are created.

Comment: but what if i had another node Cash at bank and another Cash in Hand under ASSETS would i use:           cBankRef=myRef.child("user_id").child("ASSETS").child("Cash at bank")
                    .child("stock")
                    .child("Cash in Hand");        to get all the nodes at the same time without creating multiple reference, and then use the addChildEventListener as you showed me(above);  @Grimthorr

Comment: but what if i had another node Cash at bank and another Cash in Hand under ASSETS would i use: cBankRef=myRef.child("user_id").child("ASSETS").child("Cash at bank") .child("stock") .child("Cash in Hand"); to get all the nodes at the same time without creating multiple reference, and then use the addChildEventListener as you showed me(above); @Alex Mamo

Comment: The [DatabaseReference#child()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#child(java.lang.String)) method is **not** a `SELECT` statement. To access everything underneath a node, you only need to create a reference to the highest node required, then attach a listener to that. I've updated my answer to include this clarification and another example.

Comment: thnks..i just tried but it's still giving me isnull@Grimthorr

Comment: @lewisdylanNkuranga What is giving you `null`?

Comment: i tried using 
        if (dataSnapshot.child("Cash at bank").exists()) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.child("Cash at bank").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: the cash at bank is: "+value);
        }      but the value is null but when i check the database it's there  @ Grimthorr

Comment: @lewisdylanNkuranga Make sure the "Cash at bank" value is at `/user_id/ASSETS/Cash at bank`. Can you update your question with your new database structure and some more details if this is still not working? Then I can see what's new and I'll see what I can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, i suggest you using `ValueEventListener` like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference stockRef = rootRef.child("user_id").child("ASSETS").child("Stock");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String values = ds.child("house").child("values").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", values);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
stockRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```